# How to apply ascorbic acid ppm in bread baking?

Tags: bread

According to [Effects of different doses of ascorbic acid on alveograph and bread making quality of wheat flour with average quality as starting material](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/237219916_Effects_of_different_doses_of_ascorbic_acid_on_alveograph_and_bread_making_quality_of_wheat_flour_with_average_quality_as_starting_material)  :

> the best dose of ascorbic acid that can be added for the improving average flour quality is 50-70 ppm

If I want to add 70 ppm to my flour comprising 600 grams of whole wheat flour and 100 grams of bran and wheatgerm, how many mg of ascorbic acid do I require?

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, she replied and for what it is worth:

> Dear Sir,
>
> Ascorbic acid  dosage in milling and bakery it is based on the weight of the flour.
>
> The recommendation dosage ( medium dosage) for maturate the flour is 2g/100 kg flour (Ascorbic acid can be added in the milling or in  bakery  in the mixer with the yeast, water, salt, enzymes, emulsifiers, e.g.
>
> The optimum dosage depend by the quality of the flour and by the recipe who is used : the enzymes  added, the cysteine added, the technological process, the parameter of the process, etc.
>
> To study the influence of the ascorbic acid the dosage can be  for  example: 1g /100 kg flour,   1.5 g/ 100 kg flour, 2 g ..., 2.5,   3, etc or 1g...2g...3g...4g....
>
> (10ppm=0.01 g/kg= 1g/100 kg)
>
> If you have  any questions please let me know.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Georgiana Codina

Comment: Excellent. So it's applied to flour weight only.

Answer (score 2):

I did more googling of research papers and of all three sources accessible by me, ppm is actually **per flour basis**. Quite a shocker to me.

Here are the links:[ISSN No. (Print):0975-1130ISSN No. (Online):2249-3239TheEffect ofAscorbicAcid andGlycerol onQuality ofFrozen BarbariBread](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7b5b/a87c41154a95893f6d4fb5b08de3695feefe.pdf)

[Effects of Gliadin/Glutenin and HMW‐GS/LMW‐GS Ratio on Dough Rheological Properties and Bread‐Making Potential of Wheat Varieties](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/jfq.12122)

[Method for producing danish dough](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20150216186A1/en)

I have also sent an email to Georgiana Gabriela Codina for good measure, though I am not sure if she responds to public queries.

Comment: Yes, it's helpful to be on the inside of the paywall. Be better if the Feds just tore it down. I get annoyed when I'm asked to pay for copies of my own work.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have water in your dough too, right?
Info is hidden behind the great paywall. However, I Found the whole article here: https://www.journal-of-agroalimentary.ro/admin/articole/70859L20_Vol_XIV_2008_Codina_Georgiana.pdf You may have to switch browsers to see it. Turn off your VPN etc. PPM is usually measured as milligrams per liter. but you've got a HIGHLY nonideal mixture there. Use the paper to figure out how they're measuring volume, and add the mass of ascorbic acid appropriately. **Oh**, I see they don't say *how* they measure ppm, so are *probably* just looking at total dough volume in liters, and adding ascorbic acid appropriately: 50mg/L = 50 ppm. Lord knows what happens when the stuff rises.
You might do best by emailng the author: Corresponding author: e-mail address: codinageorgiana@yahoo.com

This is an odd niche in science, and they probably follow conventions that those outside do not know.

Generally speaking, PPM is milligrams per liter. In this situation, I'd count both solids and liquids as part of the liter, so *total dough volume*.

Comment: You're wrong. PPM is parts per million and is usually done by weight. 1 ppm is 1 mg per liter of pure water, but the liquid could be mercury. PPM could also be be for a rock or a gas.

Comment: That's as I said in last sentence. Rising dough will be a problem her, so they must do the addn, before letting the dough rise, and not worry about effect of rise on ppm.

Comment: Your answer can be useful it depends on what the recipe said exactly.  But unlikely the stuff is treated as attaining a final solution, and even in that case then refering to dough V is wrong as density can be different than unity.

Comment: Yes, yes. Whole trouble is, it's a funny system and paper, which I found a non-pay copy of, doesn't say either, but does have email address for author. I gave most likely procedure they followed. For all anyone knows, they may be using a conductivity meter to measure PPM and converting using one of the 3 or 4 methods used for that-That'd be a terrible way to do it.

Comment: Members in other bread and pizza forums gave ppm as that of flour as in baker's percentage. I suspected there was more to it, therefore I am glad I asked the question here, where there are right science and food technology people to help out.

Comment: The paper isn't explicit, but it reads to me like ppm by mass of flour, i.e. they conclude that 50-70mg is added per kg of flour. The flour has some moisture content already, but it doesn't sound like the mass of any added water is included.

Comment: @ChrisH Right, that's an easy way to interpret it. But since we have the email,thr questioner can find out for sure.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I'd say it's the only logical way to interpret what's written. I'm not used to seeing corresponding authors with yahoo addresses, though given that the paper is 11 years old that might be better than an obsolete academic address.  A quick scholar search shows she's still publishing on related subjects from the same university and is a faculty member

Comment: @ChrisH I'm not certain of that, as I've seen food scientists use some really odd conventions, when compared to the hard science and tech fields. Cooking really is different, and their papers reflect that.

Comment: It seems difficult here. Sometimes peoples think different and see odd when there is not. Indeed I see the baker use ppm right and I am surprised as for some scientists don't.  But are those  scientist wrong, not that ppm means something different than what obviously means @MaxW. I even got down votes :)))

Comment: When I use ppm, it's usually to based on entire/mass volume of final product. Incl sugar, salt, etc etc. If effect is solely on flour she's calc'd in a valid way, just not one that is universally applied.

Answer (score 1):

ppm means parts per million. To answer straightly to your question

50 to 70 mg of ascorbic acid for each one kg of the overall ingredients taken as reference, presumably those explicitly mentioned or at least discussed at that point.

Since you are not dealing with analysis you can approximate and add that amount to one kg of ingredients, as for one kg plus some mg is still one kg, at least in the kitchen.

If you use less than one kg of flour then you simply go by usual proportion. For 700 g choosing the higher dose of 70 ppm means 50 mg, for instance.

Just be sure to what ppm refers to, weight of just flour(s) or flour plus water to handle it.

---

This is just to clarify to a broader audience, not necessarily because of importance in the kitchen, what ppm are and how can be used.

ppm is parts per million *by weight*. Often it is treated as mg/l just because of working with dilute solutions *in water*.  As for diluted water based solutions have a density very close to 1, in this case 1 ppm is indeed equal to 1 mg in 1 liter of solution. That is.

So if you would have to add ascorbic acid at *mg scale* to water as a base for, say, a syrup, than 1 ppm is indeed 1 mg/l.

As soon you add spoons, than ppm won't makes operatively sense and one would say 100 g for liter of water.

Finally one can refer to volumes or mixed quantities but it should be explicitly stated. Is an issue present in research as well, for instance when solutions prepared in solvent with different densities are mistakenly treated without thinking that mg/l is now different than ppm independently of concentration.

Comment: Somehow I am getting down voted with no explanation. There is no ppm in baking and ppm is exactly what I have explained. Perhaps further explaining confused someone that didn't take time enough for reading or can't transform mg/kg to g/100 kg etc.

Comment: Results that this moved from plus 30 to minus 12 for absolutely no reason.

Comment: I am adding a downvote now (there was only one before) because we have now proof that your answer is factually incorrect. The OP contacted the paper's author, and she confirmed that the ppm in her paper are calculated as bakers' percentage, relative to the flour weight. This is indeed counterintuitive when compared to use in other fields, but it still makes your answer incorrect, and as such it deserves to get lower in the ordering of answers.

Comment: It is exactly what I have said. Is weight to weight. Are you able to read my answer? @rumtscho. It is not counterintuitive!  There are not other uses if things are done correctly. It is exactly what I clarify in the extension. Could you see my straight answer? 50 to 70 mg of ascorbic acid for each 1 kg of overall ingredients. Strictly 1 ppm is 1 in 1 million, not 1 in 1 million and 1! Which I have also explained.  Hopefully it will be read also by people more ponderant and more quickly understanding proportion and concentration. But it is not unfair. Voting down a right answer is wrong

Comment: I read your answer to mean that it is weight of the ascorbic acid to weight of the dough, because you say "for each one kg of overall ingredients". That is, if somebody uses 600 g of flour and 400 g of water, that would mean using 0.5 g ascorbic acid to make 50 ppm. But we now learned that it should be weight of the acid to weight of the flour, ignoring the other ingredients, which would mean 0.3 g for 50 ppm in that example case.

Comment: The overall of what ppp refer to. Explanation 500000 ppm still refer to 1 million, not 1.5 millions.  I thought it should be evident . And even more when I invite OP to check what ppm referred to, if flour or, just in case, the *weight* of flour plus water.  The latter is possible as it depends on who wrote a recipe. You can see the dough was brought in by someone else and I have promptly comment.  Misuse of ppm, and especially mixing weight and volume, is what I contrast here and in my research environment as well. Chemist here ;)

Comment: @rumtscho I will change to "overall ingredient to what ppm refers to as stated in the recipe". If a recipe is formulated as x g of X , y g of Y and z ppm of z, then z has to be calculated with x+y in mind. I am sure is now clear to you but I can avoid misunderstanding by others.

Comment: It is not "stated in the recipe". The OP read it in a research paper, and the research paper did not state what it refers to. Apparently, there is a convention in the field that it refers to the weight of the flour. So in principle, your answer states half of the convention (that it should be per weight) but not the other important half (per weight of what). It also makes it seem that the convention you use (per weight) is the only acceptable one.

Comment: As per the Q - how much is 70 ppm for 700 overall g of flour - the *straight!* answer is 49 mg with of course I have rounded to 50. There is no convention. Surprisingly) everybody - bakers, authors of the papers, myself - do the right thing.. It is literally number of part of something in a million parts measured the same way. No convention. The only thing acceptable is to neglect the ppm weight added as I have explained. In the baker units 2g in 100 kg or 2 g in 100.002 kg is the same. This is implied when using concentration in ppm because the stuff added is negligible to the overall.

Comment: And your insistence that there is no convention is exactly why I think your answer should be downvoted - after the new information revealed in the other answers, I am convinced that there is a convention. It is not about adding 2 ppm changing the overall amount, it is about relating it to the weight of the flour, as opposed to the weight of the dough.

Comment: @rumscho I didn't mention any dough at all! I just mention that one has to be sure to what amount ppm refer to. Ppm means parts per million of the whole thing you refer to. The most natural would be to flour and I given the nuneric value. 70 ppm means 50 ppm in the OP context. Just warn to be sure what the whole is, and he did it by contacting that person. It is simple as that. Also added that 2 g in 100 kg is not truly 20 ppm but at baking as well in chemistry it goes smoothly. Not understanding things is not a good reason for down voting. Without addressing things emerged in wrong or tentati

Comment: ....tentative answers and comments my answer would have been 70 ppm in 700 g flour is 50 mg. Dot.